# Writing a Simpler Version of tryCatch in R

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

In R there is a function called `tryCatch()` that can recover from an error. I've only ever seen the error handling step written as a function. For example, adding `error=function(e){0}` will return the value of zero upon error. Is there a simpler way to define `tryCatch()` without having to write the error as a function? If not, then why?

I would prefer a syntax and result like this:

```
x <- tryCatch(sqrt("a"), 0)
#> x
#> [1] 0
```

You could write your own `tryCatch()` wrapper function (example below), but I was wondering if there is already another function in an existing package or something I am missing in the `tryCatch()` documentation that makes this possible.

**Solution written as a wrapper function**:

```
iferror <- function(expr, error_expr){
  tryCatch(expr, error=function(e){error_expr})
}
x <- iferror(sqrt("a"), 0)
#> x
#> [1] 0
```

**Note**: This is *not* a question of how to use `tryCatch()`, but rather how the syntax of it can be made less verbose.

Comment: `tryCatch` also catches warnings. If you want a special case, do you expect to ignore that capability? How about this: `f0 <- function(e) 0`, then `tryCatch(expr, error=f0)`. It's not saving much, but at least your call to `tryCatch` is less cluttered.

Comment: I'm aware that `tryCatch()` handles warnings and a `finally` expression, but not as concerned with that here. In your example, the error still is being defined as a function. This seems unnecessarily verbose, but maybe that's just the way you gotta do it with `tryCatch()`

Comment: Ok, how about `purrr::possibly(sqrt,0)('a')`. Since `possibly` returns a wrapped-function, you need to call it and then use the return to call again, so it's a little obscure, I admit.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is using the `has_error()` function from the **testit** package. Although the CRAN version does not allow for controlling the suppression of the error message.

**Example**:

```
ifelse(testit::has_error(sqrt("a")), 0)
#> Error in sqrt("a") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
#> [1] 0
```